# how to implement pagination on json file

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

> the table shows data from json file but all the data appears in one page, i need to implement pagination to control the data to show 10 rows on every page.

```
$.ajax({
url:"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    var content = $('#body-content');
    $.each(data, function(i, item){
        var row = `
        <tr class="bg-light">
            <th scope="row">${item.userId}</th>
            <td>${item.id}</td>
            <td>605</td>
            <td>2/2/2020</td>
            <td>أحمد إبراهيم جلال</td>
            <td>
                <div class="lawyer__grade">
                    <i class="far fa-star lawyer__grade__empty"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star lawyer__grade__full"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star lawyer__grade__full"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star lawyer__grade__full"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star lawyer__grade__full"></i>     
                </div>
            </td>
        <td>150 ج</td>
    </tr>
        ` ;
        content.append(row);
    });
}
```

});

[there is my full code on codepen](https://codepen.io/mona90/pen/dyorqdR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that dynamicly on the server, by creating some html files each represents a page and each contains 10 items of your data, or you can do some tricks with JavaScript on client side, by dividing your html into sets each set groups 10 items of your data, and hide all the sets except for the first one, and create some buttons for the user to simulate pagination, previous and next, when the user clicks next you need to hide all of the sets and show the second one, and build you logic...